# Django python - how to put all HttpResponses through a function

Tags: python, django, httpresponse, http-request

I have urls.py which routes a HttpRequest to a particular view function. These view functions all return a dictionary object. How can I pass all these return objects through a function which dumps to Json and wraps in an HttpResponse?

Thanks

Comment: Originally in each view function I had:

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(responseObject))

Now I just return the responseObject and want to wrap it in the HttpResponse at the next level uo

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a [render_decorator](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1733/) is what you want.
Usage:

```
@render('index.html', ('json',))
def my_view(request)
    #do something
    return {'key': 'value'}
```

Or this [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/622/), which is used on a function that returns a dict to get a JSON view.

Comment: But is this then rendering some html file? So far I have managed to avoid that.

Comment: Actually I didn't see that this decorator can also be used to return a json response

Comment: @user973758 I have updated my answer with link to another snippet. Anyway, using decorators is the best approach for you question, i think.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Django Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs#process-response) to process your response object. Implement the `process_response` method in your custom middleware. Use the dictionary that is created by the view and convert it to the json you desire. Then pass it to the below function which will ensure the actual response received is json.

```
def render_json_response(data):
    """Sends an HttpResponse with the X-JSON header and the right mimetype."""
    resp = HttpResponse(data, mimetype=("application/json;"))
    resp['X-JSON'] = data
    return resp
```

Also discovered this `ajax_request decorator - returns JsonResponse with dict as content` available in the [Django Annoying](https://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/wiki/Home) project

Answer (score 0):

How about subclassing `HttpResponse`? I'm using this in views to return json:

```
import simplejson
from django.http import HttpResponse

class JsonResponse(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(JsonResponse, self).__init__(
            content=simplejson.dumps(data),
            mimetype='application/json; charset=utf8')
```